# Change controls style with CSS in OpenLayers 3.5.0

Tags: openlayers-3

My question is simple: It is possible to change the controls button styles with a CSS ? And if I do that, Can I don't load the CSS of OpenLayers ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And the answer is also simple:

```
.ol-control button{ 
    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.85) !important;
}
```

The `!important` is to overwrite the default style.

And no, do load their css. It is too much to substitute.

Comment: That change the background-color of a button, but if I want to replace by a picture for example ? When I test that `background:url(../style/over.png)no-repeat center;` I don't have result

Comment: But this is CSS work, your question is about `Is it possible`, I gave you an example. Maybe your image doesn't exist, maybe the path is wrong. Your CSS syntax... check all.